# Referencing two jnlp files from same html page - Java Webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start

Is there a way to reference two JNLP files from the same HTML page?

I have two links on my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Test</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('launchDA.jnlp');">Launch Data Adapter</a>
        <br>
        <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
        <a href="javascript:deployJava.launchWebStartApplication('launch.jnlp');">Launch HMI</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each of which would in theory launch different java .jar files.

It seems though in practice, clicking one or the other launches only one of the jnlp files. This does seem to work when I double click the html file to open in browser and click the links but not when I'm hosting it on a tomcat server and go to the page through localhost:8080/etc/launch.html.